# When comparing old text and new text and adding new text to the old one it adds more text than usal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def compare_and_delete_duplicates(file1, file2, output_file):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        text1 = set(f1.readlines())
        text2 = set(f2.readlines())
        unique_text = text1.difference(text2)

with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
     output.write(''.join(unique_text) + '\n')
     
file1 = 'a.txt'
file2 = 'b.txt'
output_file = 'a.txt'

compare_and_delete_duplicates(file1, file2, output_file)

def save_file_to_file(source_file, destination_file):
    with open(source_file, 'r') as source, open(destination_file, 'a') as destination:
        source_content = source.read()
        destination.write(source_content + "\n")

source_file = 'a.txt'
destination_file = 'b.txt'
save_file_to_file(source_file, destination_file)
```

this code compares old text to new text then adds the new text to the old one BUT, when it adds the new text it adds old text with it for example :

a.txt = """
a
b
c
g"""

b.txt = """
a
b
c
d
e
f"""

when I start the program it will add to a.txt = :"ag" and it will add for b.txt = "ag" aswell I just want to add the new text to the old file.

I tried everything but I got no results I tried changing
destination.write(source_content + "\n")
to
destination.write("\n" + source_content)

Comment: Hi Daemon! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify what your desired output should be in the example you gave?

Comment: I just want to compare the first file and the second file remove the common and then use the new text then save the new text in the second file.

Comment: what your desired output should be in the example you gave. Please answer the question literally

Comment: the output should be "G" and then it adds "G" to b.txt

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with indentation:

```
def compare_and_delete_duplicates(file1, file2, output_file):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        # split each line on spaces
        text1 = set(f1.read().split())
        text2 = set(f2.read().split())
        unique_text = text1.difference(text2)

    with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
        # add the unique text to the output file
        output.write('\n'.join(unique_text))
     
file1 = 'a.txt'
file2 = 'b.txt'
output_file = 'a.txt'

compare_and_delete_duplicates(file1, file2, output_file)
```

This will change the contents of `a.txt` to be "g"

Comment: I got the same problem again, a.txt was "was" and the other got "like" and "well" I started program twice now in a.txt I got "waslike" and the other it worked fine. when I runned it 3 times I got "waslikelike"

Comment: I want to use the new text that was "like" for once and then delete "like" and add it to b.txt

Comment: you might have to make it clearer for me. 1. What is in a.txt? 2.What is in b.txt? 3. What would you like to be in a.txt? 4. What would you like to be in b.txt?

Comment: for some reason when I write "g" in a.txt I get "ganger" in b.txt

Comment: have you ever debugged before?

Comment: nope I haven't debugged before, do I use pdb?

Comment: you can use that, or something else

Comment: e.g. in Visual Studio Code, there's a debugger built in

Comment: 1. What is in a.txt? 2.What is in b.txt? 3. What would you like to be in a.txt? 4. What would you like to be in b.txt?